# The use of design patterns in R

Tags: oop, r, design-patterns

The use of [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) in programming is wide spread across many programming languages. A number of examples are the [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), or [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern. Many of these patterns use object orientation to create abstraction and encapsulation in the code, they aim at make code re-usable and structured. Many of these design patterns could also be used in R, maybe by using the [proto](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proto/index.html) library, or standard R object orientation?

My questions are:

- What base code (S3, S4) / packages (proto, R.oo) can I use to reproduce design patterns as for example mentioned in the book by Gamma et al?
- Are there examples of design patterns implemented in R, both in base R, or in packages?

Comment: The R.oo package provides OOP-like functionality in R (using S3 classes).  It does not support the full range of OOP features and as such would not support the fulll range of OOP-based design patterns.  I would also look at S4 classes http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/S-Workshop/Gentleman/S4Objects.pdf

Comment: S4 classes look promising, although the manner of constructing objects looks a bit clunky in comparison to e.g. Python.

Comment: I've implemented a few design patterns sketched out in "Head First Design Patterns" using Reference classes. They map more closely to OO use in other languages than S4 methods, say, so involve less translation.

Comment: Could you post a link to your work as an answer? Or if it is not already online, post some of the code as an answer?

Comment: Okay, I put an example of the Singleton Pattern here: https://gist.github.com/1953641 This was really a formal exercise and perhaps somewhat arcane for R users. The `memoise` package can do this much easier, though I did have a use case. The basic idea for the structure came from the Head First book.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question falls into the same line as the R/oop question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521651/r-and-object-oriented-programming#question), it is too broad, and is not a good fit for the Q&A format on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some examples of design patterns:

- The [`system.time()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.time.html) function seems to behave much like a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). However, almost exclusively decorators are mentioned in the context of object oriented programming. But still, it has the feel of a decorator, it extends (or decorates) an existing piece of code (in OOP always an object) with additional functionality without any need to change the piece of code. Here `system.time()` is shown in action:

  ```
  system.time(bla <- Sys.sleep(1000))
  ```
- @jverzani posted an example of singleton pattern [on github](https://gist.github.com/1953641).
- An example of a Strategy Design Pattern is the `apply` family of functions. The functionality of looping over the given object is generic, the function that is applied (the strategy) is chosen when the user supplies the function.