# Generic "classes" inside R

Tags: r, generics, data-structures, stack

I have written a stack "class" with the following functions: `add`, `push`, `pop`, `size`, `isEmpty`, `clear` (and some more).

I'd like to use this "class" as a generic in R, so I may create multiple instances of stacks within my script. How do I go about doing this?

*(I have class in quotes because my stack functions are written in a different script (not necessarily the definition of a class per se)*

Thanks in advance

```
list <- ""
cursor = 0

#Initializes stack to empty
stack <- function(){
list <- c()
cursor = -1

assign("list",list,.GlobalEnv)
assign("cursor",cursor,.GlobalEnv)
}


#Where item is a item to be added to generic list
push <- function(item){
if(size(list) == 0){
    add(item, -1)
}else{
    add(item, 0)        
}
assign("list",list,.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: There really not much to go on in this question.  A bit of code example will be useful.

Comment: Have you tried googling "R S4 classes" and reading the manuals and guides that pop up?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I haven't looked in to S4 Classes because I am not sure I need them. In this case, is that style necessary? Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be what you're looking for (and should thus be closed as a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521651/r-and-object-oriented-programming

Comment: @laemtao, your best bet at keeping this question open is to provide some code.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Reviewing answers. Hope this question helped those with similar inquires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simpler version of the stack implementation @GSee references that avoids using any of the formal object-orientation systems available in R. Simplification proceeds from the fact that all functions in R are closures and functions created during a function call are bound to the environment created for that call.

```
new_stack <- function() {
    stack <- vector()
    push <- function(x) stack <<- c(stack, x)
    pop <- function() {
        tmp<-tail(stack, 1)
        stack<<-stack[-length(stack)]
        return(tmp)
    }
    structure(list(pop=pop, push=push), class='stack')
}

x <- new_stack()
x$push(1:3)
x$pop()
# [1] 3
x$pop()
# [1] 2
```

Here's an S4 implementation, for comparison.

```
setClass('Stack', 
         representation(list='list', cursor='numeric'),  # type defs
         prototype(list=list(), cursor=NA_real_))        # default values

setGeneric('push', function(obj, ...) standardGeneric('push'))
setMethod('push', signature(obj='Stack'), 
    function(obj, x) {
        obj@list <- c(x, obj@list)
        obj
})

setGeneric('pop', function(obj, ...) standardGeneric('pop'))
setMethod('pop', signature(obj='Stack'),
    function(obj) {
        obj@cursor <- obj@list[[1]]
        obj@list <- obj@list[-1]
        obj
    }
)

x <- new('Stack')

# cursor is empty to start
x@cursor
#[1] NA

# add items
x <- push(x, 1)
x <- push(x, 2)

# pop them (move next item to cursor, remove from list)
x <- pop(x)
x@cursor
# [1] 2
x <- pop(x)
x@cursor
# [1] 1
```

Comment: The use of `on.exit` is a bit clumsy (and unnecessary).

Comment: @hadley thanks for your comments. rather than the usual tmp-remove-return, I thought I'd exercise some creativity. sorry to displease. do you mean it's clumsy in terms of readability? I would discourage such an action in a longer function, but here it seemed pretty harmless.

Comment: What are alternatives to on.exit? (still learning S4 mannerisms and conventions)

Comment: @laemtao see the definition of `stack@push` in @GSee's answer.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde it's clumsy in that you usually see `on.exit` used to ensure something happens if the function exits with an error - so when I saw it, I immediately started trying to figure out what would throw an error.

Comment: @hadley I've encountered `on.exit` on only a few occasions in my short time with R, and didn't perceive how this usage might be misleading. Brevity may be the soul of wit, but clarity is the spirit of cooperation! Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are specifically talking about a stack "class" with push and pop methods, here's an implementation by Jeff Ryan taken from [Introducing Closures](http://www.lemnica.com/esotericR/Introducing-Closures/) which you can read for an explanation of what's going on here.

```
new_stack <- function() { 
  stack <- new.env()
  stack$.Data <- vector()
  stack$push <- function(x) .Data <<- c(.Data,x)
  stack$pop  <- function() {
    tmp <- .Data[length(.Data)]
    .Data <<- .Data[-length(.Data)]
    return(tmp)
  }
  environment(stack$push) <- as.environment(stack)
  environment(stack$pop) <- as.environment(stack)
  class(stack) <- "stack"
  stack
}

> x <- new_stack()
> x$push(1:3)
> x$pop()
[1] 3
> x$pop()
[1] 2
```

Then, if you create S3 generics...

```
push <- function(x, value, ...) UseMethod("push")
pop  <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("pop")
push.stack <- function(x, value, ...) x$push(value)
pop.stack  <- function(x) x$pop()

> push(x, 5)
> pop(x)
[1] 5
> pop(x)
[1] 1
```

Comment: His implementation is overly complicated, probably for pedagogical reasons. I added an Answer with a simplified version.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde unfortunately that article about closures doesn't really talk about closures at all :/

Comment: @hadely are you referring to the dead link or a lack of substantive information on closures in the article?