# What are the implications of calling a function using an object in R?

Tags: r, reference, call

Since i have just made my foray into R, I came across the following set of function calls:

```
myFunc<-function(x=matrix())
 {
  temp<-NULL
  set<-function(y)
  {
   x<<-y
   temp<<-NULL
  }
  get(){ x }
  setT(t){ temp<<-T }
  getT(){ Temp }
  list(set=set,get=get,setT=setT,getT=getT)
 }
```

In the Second function with the following header:

```
anotherFunc<-function(x)
```

There is a statement that reads,

```
randomvariable<-x$getT()
```

Now what i'm trying to understand is how is this statement different from 
any other function call. What are the implications of referencing x to call the function getT(). Is there any similarity between the call by reference used in Java, C++?

PS- In case there is mistake in the question format, please do mention since i'm new to SO.

Comment: Please make your code reproducible.

Comment: By mentioning reproducible, do you want me to add the second function?

Comment: This question is too broad, SO is for exact practical problems. Are there similarities? Yeah, there are functions and you call them. Assuming what you're alluding to here is the fact this list kind of looks like a ghetto object well it kind of does, but what you're doing in R looks more like a HashMap with functors in java than an object

Comment: I agree--this looks like a kludgy attempt at a closure, but hard to tell without seeing all of the defined functions (setT and getT are missing).  You may find this comparison of R's different OO-like systems helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522858/636656

Comment: Thank you all for the replies, i kind of got to know my mistake, and i agree i wasn't able to present it in a crisp and precise manner. Will take care of it in the future.