# I can call a function, but another function's internal call cannot find the function

Tags: r

I have an object, suppose it's called `obj`. I can call a function, `obj$a()` and that works. However, when I call `obj$b()`, which internally calls `self$a()`, it throws an error saying that it cannot find the `a` function. What can I do?

Comment: Might be helpful if you posted some code to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: R's OOP is not so fancy as all that, as far as I know. You probably want to just go `with(obj, ... do stuff ...)`.

Comment: `self` isn't really a thing in R...

Comment: I'm pretty unknowledgeable about this stuff but `obj = within(list(), {
  a = function(x) 2*x;
  b = function(x,y) a(x) + y
})` "works", in the sense that I can do `obj$b(11,22)`. This Q&A might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521651/r-and-object-oriented-programming

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the functions share an environment / are in the same closure. You could encapsulate them in a dummy function. Look at this example:

```
gives_error <- list(a = function() { 
                          print("Hello from a")
                        },
                    b = function(){
                          print("Hello from b")
                          a()
                    })

gives_error$b()


will_work <-
    (function() {
        a = function(){ 
            print("Hello from a")
        }
        b = function(){
            print("Hello from b")
            a()
        }
        list(a = a, b = b)
    })()

will_work$b()
```